# Split Information in file and read them

Tags: java, file, parsing, constructor

I have a text file:

```
Jim Webb 27 Axelrod Street
Hillary Sanders 92 California Street
Bernie Trudeau 46 Pot Street
Barack Bush 883 White Ave
Mary Warren 736 Something Rd
Donald Crump 65 Debate Street
```

I need to parse a persons, first name, last name, and address (the information after the persons last name).

This is my attempt at it:

```
public Parse() {
        parseFiles();
    }

    void parseFiles() {
        try {
            File file = new File("school.txt");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                String s = sc.nextLine();
                String[] splited = s.split("\\s+");
                for (int i = 0; i < splited.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(splited[i]);
                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found\n");
        }

    }

}
```

Unfortunately, my method parses every single line space by space, which works for the first name and last name, but doesn't work for the address, as I want the address to be one whole string, not a bunch of strings separated by spaces.

For instances, I have a student class like this:

```
public Student(String name, String lastName, String address) {
this.name = name
//etc... 
}
```

Where I want to initialize a student every time (after every line read), but with my implementation, I can only do that for the persons first and last name, how would I go about parsing the address as a whole separately? Then being able to call the Student Constructor.

Comment: Why don't you read by line and split into the array. And then take everything after the third element to be the address?

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `.next()` to get the first name and the last name, and `.nextLine()` right after to get the rest of the line, like this:

```
String firstName = sc.next();
String lastName = sc.next();
String address = sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: Hmm this certainly works, however at a certain point I seem to get a NoSuchElementException.

Comment: Hmm, nevermind I fixed it by changing the while loop from hasNextLine to hasNext.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the file stucture will **NEVER** change, the address will always be at the last two positions. Add an `if` clause in your `for`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < splited.length; i++) {
    if(i >= (splited.length - 2)) {
        System.out.println(splited[i] + " " + splited[i + 1]);
        break;
    } else
        System.out.println(splited[i]);
}
```

You can further tweak the for-loop to stop before the `(splited.length - 2)` position:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (splited.length - 2); i++) {
    System.out.println(splited[i]);
}
System.out.println(splited[splited.length - 2] + " " + splited[splited.length - 1]);
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but I'd like to simplify my code as much as possible. Jano's solution does that, nonetheless +1 to you.

Comment: Yeah, his answer is better (and also more "production-friendly"), but thank you anyway!